# About split function of Visual Basic

Tags: vba, split

I want to Split the carton no line by line from "ASN_importdata" to new table "ASN_importdata2"
But the result is not my expected.
Someone can help me to solve this problem?

Source_ASN_Importdata:

```
CNO       SKU    QTY    GW 
---------------------------------
Y.01-03   AAA    600    60
Y.04      AAB    100    10
Y.04      AAC    100    10
Y.05-07   ABC    600    60
```

Expected:

```
CNO       SKU    QTY    GW
---------------------------------
01        AAA    200    20
02        AAA    200    20
03        AAA    200    20
04        AAB    100    10
04        AAC    100    10
05        ABC    200    20
06        ABC    200    20
07        ABC    200    20
```

Actual result:

```
CNO       SKU    QTY    GW
---------------------------------
01        AAA    300    30
03        AAA    300    30
04        AAB    100    10
04        AAC    100    10
05        ABC    300    30
07        ABC    300    30
```

Code:

```
Private Sub txtconvert_Click()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsSource As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsOut As DAO.Recordset
    Dim SplitToRows() As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim strCTN As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsSource = db.OpenRecordset("ASN_Importdata")
    Set rsOut = db.OpenRecordset("ASN_Importdata2")
    If (Not rsSource.BOF And Not rsSource.EOF) Then

    Do Until rsSource.EOF
        strCTN = Replace(rsSource!cno, "Y.", "")

        SplitToRows = Split(strCTN, "-", -1)

        For I = 0 To CInt(UBound(SplitToRows()))
        rsOut.AddNew

        rsOut("CNO") = SplitToRows(I)
        rsOut("SKU") = rsSource("SKU")
        rsOut("QTY") = rsSource("QTY") / (UBound(SplitToRows()) + 1)
        rsOut("GW") = rsSource("GW") / (UBound(SplitToRows()) + 1)
        rsOut.Update

    Next I
        rsSource.MoveNext
    Loop
        MsgBox "Done!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No record"
    End If
    rsSource.Close
    Set rsSource = Nothing
    rsOut.Close
    Set rsOut = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `For I = 0 To CInt(SplitRows(UBound(SplitRows)))` and `rsOut("CNO")=Format(I,"00")` then similar as the For To for the last two output fields.

Comment: Thank for your comment!! I modify it to "For I = SplitToRows(CInt(LBound(SplitToRows))) To SplitToRows(CInt(UBound(SplitToRows)))". It gonna be work!!